# Supabase: get table count in rest mode

Tags: rest, http, supabase, postgrest

There is any way to get the table count in rest mode?

I'm using query params like:

```bash
https://urt.to.supabase/rest/v1/table?select=field,another_field
```

I was googling it out but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to add `Prefer: count=exact` to the request header.

Example of this using curl would be like this:

```bash
curl "https://urt.to.supabase/rest/v1/table?select=field,another_field" -I \
  -H "Prefer: count=exact"
```

The count value will be the number after `/` on the `content-range` header on your response. In the following example, row count is 3573458.

```
Content-Range: 0-24/3573458
```

You can read more about it on postgrest documentation [here](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=count#exact-count).

Note that with the Supabase.js library, you easily get the count of

```js
const { data, error, count } = await supabase
  .from('cities')
  .select('name', { count: 'exact' })
```

You can read more about it on the [official docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select#querying-with-count-option).

Comment: I already tried sending the Prefer header to "count=exact" and I'm only receiving the rows, no count

Comment: @DiegoUlloa The count will not be returned as a body, but will be included in `content-range` header as stated here. https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=count#exact-count Could you check if you are getting the proper count value in the header of your response?

Comment: If I specify the `count=exact` Prefer header I get `content-range: 0-12/13`, otherwise `content-range: 0-12/*`. I'm using SWR to fetch data, so I'm researching how to get it

Comment: @DiegoUlloa Yup, in that case, 13 is the count that you are looking for!

Comment: do you know how to send the `{ head: true }` param into the header according to this extract from the documentation?: `if you don't want to return any rows, you can use { count: 'exact', head: true }`

Comment: things I tried: `{ Prefer: "count=exact; head=true" }`, `{ Prefer: "count=exact, head=true" }`, `{ Prefer: "count=exact; head=1" }`, `{ Prefer: "count=exact, head=1" }`

Comment: @DiegoUlloa Yup, `{ head: true }` just changes the http method to a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` request. No need to change any header parameters!  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods